# std::basic_string::reserve() specifics

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I was reading the standard on `std::basic_string::reserve(size_type res_arg=0)`. It says this:

> `void reserve(size_type res_arg=0);`
>
> The member function `reserve()` is a directive that informs a
>   `basic_­string` object of a planned change in size, so that it can
>   manage the storage allocation accordingly.
>
> Effects: After `reserve()`, `capacity()` is greater or equal to the
>   argument of reserve. [ **Note: Calling `reserve()` with a res_­arg
>   argument less than `capacity()` is in effect a non-binding shrink
>   request. A call with `res_­arg <= size()` is in effect a non-binding
>   shrink-to-fit request.  — end note ]**
>
> Throws: length_­error if `res_­arg > max_­size()`

The standard seems to be making a distinction between calling `reserve()` where `res_arg < capacity()` and calling `reserve()` where `res_arg <= size()`.

`res_arg <= size()` is easy to understand, `shrink_to_fit()` is called and the implementation is free to do whatever it wants since it's non-binding.

But what about cases where `res_arg < capacity()`? The standard says "*a non-binding shrink request*" and not "*a non-binding **shrink-to-fit** request*". What is the difference between a shrink-to-fit request and a shrink request? Is this just an unfortunate inconsistency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string::shrink_to_fit()` will shrink the `capacity()` to the `size()`.  That is differnt then shrinking the `capacity()` to a number less than `capacity()` but more than `size()`.  In effect

```
std:string foo = "test";
foo.reserve(20);      // capaicty:20 size:4
foo.reserve(10);      // capaicty:10 size:4
foo.reserve(20);      // capaicty:20 size:4
foo.shrink_to_fit();  // capaicty:04 size:4
```

Comment: I see. So the only reason "shrink" is used instead of "strink_to_fit" for the former is because of the requirements of that request? There's no `shrink` method (but there is a `shrink_to_fit`) or any of the like, which got me confused.

Comment: @GillBates Yes.  It is not a `shrink_to_fit`, but just a shrinking of the buffer.  A `shrink_to_fit` has specific requirements if it is not a non op.